# Stored Procedure en MySQL con Prepared Statement devuelve sólo el primer valor en lugar de todos

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedure, prepared-statements

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`prueba`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `pPRUEBA`(IN `_table` VARCHAR(20), IN `_ids` VARCHAR(200), IN `_primary` VARCHAR(20))
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
SET @param = _ids;
SET @sql_ =CONCAT(‘SELECT * FROM ‘,_table,’ WHERE ‘,_primary,’ IN (?)’);
PREPARE statement_ FROM @sql_;
EXECUTE statement_ using @param;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement_;
END
```

Desde PHP llamo al procedimiento almacenado ($cnn es la conexion persistente ya establecida y funcionando):

```
$param = sprintf(“%s, %s, %s”,
                GetSQLValueString(‘estados’, “text”),
                GetSQLValueString(‘0,1,2,3’, “text”),
                GetSQLValueString(‘IdEstado’, “text”));
$query = “CALL pPRUEBA (” . $param . “)”;
$rs = mysqli_query($cnn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($cnn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_all($rs, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Pero el resultado que devuelve es solamente del primer indice pasado como parametro:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [“IdEstado”]=> string(1) “0” [“Nombre”]=> string(4) “BAJA” } }
```

La tabla está declarada así:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `estados` (
  `IdEstado` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdEstado`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Con los siguientes registros:

```
INSERT INTO `estados` (`IdEstado`, `Nombre`) VALUES
(0, 'BAJA'),
(1, 'HABILITADO'),
(2, 'CORTADO'),
(3, 'PENDIENTE INSTALACION'),
(4, 'CAMBIO DE TARIFA'),
(5, 'PENDIENTE DE BAJA'),
(6, 'PENDIENTE DE CORTE'),
(7, 'PENDIENTE DE RECONEXION'),
(8, 'PENDIENTE DE SUSPENSION'),
(9, 'SUSPENDIDO');
```

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: probaste el resultado del SP??? como retorna la información???

Comment: La prueba del procedimiento desde phpMyAdmin también devuelve solamente el primer índice pasado como parámetro

Comment: entonces lo que esta mal es tu SP

Comment: Si. El problema es el SP. Pero no sé que parte del mismo es la incorrecta, por eso agrego todo lo demás para ver si alguien me puede ayudar. Para el ejemplo citado, el resultado del Prepared Statement debería ser: `SELECT * FROM enlaces WHERE IdEnlace IN (0,1,2,3)`. Si ejecuto esta consulta en phpMyAdmin el resultado es el correcto. Pero en el SP no puedo ver como queda el Prepared Statement...

Comment: prueba con **SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',_table,' WHERE ',_primary,' IN (?)');** parece que tienes problemas con los caracteres de comilla simple

Comment: El resultado es el mismo, las comillas están bien son todas comillas simples...

Comment: **CONCAT(‘SELECT * FROM ‘,_table,’ WHERE ‘,_primary,’ IN (?)’);** revisa los caracteres, no son comillas simples

Answer (score 0):

```
CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',_table,' WHERE ',_primary,' IN (?)');


CONCAT(‘SELECT * FROM ‘,_table,’ WHERE ‘,_primary,’ IN (?)’);
```

El problema son tus caracteres de comillas simples.

Comment: No es el problema las comillas, en mi código están bien. Al trasladar el código aquí y marcarlo como código se ve distinto, con ese otro carácter.